# What is the name of this popup in IntelliJ IDEA? Object tree viewer?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I debug an app and the process stops at a breakpoint, I can examine details of some objects. I hover over it and a small popup appears

[image]

then I can press the popup to get more details about the object.

[image]

What is the name of this popup?

I am trying to create a shortcut to it or to decrease hover time, but I don't know its name. Searching for "tree" or "object tree" returned no result in the `Ctrl+Shift+A` search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **`Quick Evaluate Expression`** popup. You can perform the action on any variable. Search for the key mapping using that term. Usually it is invoked by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the variable name.

Comment: `Alt + Click` does not invoke the popup in my case. Only the hover does.

Comment: Are you talking about the yellow popup or the window popup? The window popup can be invoked by whatever shortcut is bound to "Quick Evaluate Expression" in your key-map.